# Is there a way to have a base class for Jasmine Unit Tests (Angular 4)?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I have several .spec.ts files that all need the following beforeEach:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule, HttpModule, CovalentHttpModule.forRoot({
        interceptors: [{
          interceptor: CustomInterceptorService, paths: ['**'],
        }],
      }),],
      declarations: [LoginComponent],
      providers: [AuthService, { provide: Router, useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate'); } }, LoggingService, CustomInterceptorService],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

**Is there a way to outsource this TestBed configuration ?** Right now I have to adapt every new test file with the same imports and providers.

I am looking for something like a Base Unit Test. Is it possible with Jasmine ?

Comment: by `base class` what you exactly mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This case isn't really specific to Jasmine. If a function should be reused, this can be done by means of JavaScript/TypeScript.

A helper function:

```
export const setupFooTestbed = async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({...})...
});
...
beforeEach(setupFooTestbed);
```

Or it can be a base class for [`TestModuleMetadata`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestModuleMetadata) object that is accepted by `TestBed.configureTestingModule`:

```
export FooTestModuleMetadata implements TestModuleMetadata { ... }
...
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule(new FooTestModuleMetadata)...
}));
```

Or a common testing module can be supplied to [`initTestEnvironment` method](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed#static-members):

> Initialize the environment for testing with a compiler factory, a PlatformRef, and an angular module. These are common to every test in the suite.
>
> This may only be called once, to set up the common providers for the current test suite on the current platform. If you absolutely need to change the providers, first use resetTestEnvironment.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks